# Kerning for arabic digits?

Tags: spacing, symbols, typography, kerning

In most fonts, arabic digits have nonproportional width, meaning that 1 and 8 have exactly the same width even if the former has a smaller natural width. This is good for typesetting tables, but in running text this distracts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
  Look at this figure:
  1,123,456 cars.
  How to remove the extra space between the first two 1?
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

I feel that there's slightly too much space between the first two "ones". What do the typographers think about this issue? How do I enable kerning of digits (or just usage of their natural width) in running text?

Comment: in metal fonts, there were two different sets of digits, one to be used in text ("natural" width), and a different one (monowidth) to be used in tables.  computerized composition "simplified" this, choosing the monowidth version since much of the early computer-generated material was tables.  how proportional widths might be enabled for digits depends on the flavor of tex being used, and how fonts are accessed.  for "traditional" tex, using `tfm` files, the original font could be cloned under a new name, and new widths assigned manually via a `.pl` file.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Wow. So no hope for a `\propdigits` command or environment?

Comment: probably someone could construct such a command, but it would likely have to be different for every font, and i'm not aware that anyone has done it yet.  (someone else may know different.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OpenType has among its many [standard font features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typographic_features) the option `tnum` for “Tabular Figures” (each digit has the same width, suitable for tables) *vs.* `pnum` for “Proportional Figures” (digits may have varying widths, as you requested).

Note that this is distinct from, and orthogonal to, the choice of `lnum` “Lining Figures” *vs.* `onum` “Oldstyle Figures”.

The OpenType-capable TeX engines LuaTeX & XɘTeX can access these glyphs if the font you’re using supports those features. Try this example with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}
{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}}     0123456789}

{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining,Proportional}}   0123456789}

{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={OldStyle,Monospaced}}   0123456789}

{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}} 0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

(The alternate figures in `fontspec`’s default typeface, Latin Modern Roman, are ugly; avoid them.)