# Why are these sentences in Libertine so cramped and what can I do about it?

Tags: spacing, best-practices, kerning, libertine

Recently I was writing a document in LaTeX using [Linux Libertine](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/linuxlibertine/). Overall I love this font, but I found a strange case of italicized text where there is almost no space between the word *of* and a successive mathematical expression. Picture, with MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\textit{Let $d$ be the dimension of $V$ or of ${}^LG$.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To my eye both *of*'s are way too close to the following text and it looks glaringly bad.

I suspect this is happening because of the default spacing parameters for an italic f are small. And that scares me a bit because these are very [low-level parameters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10455) (at least in LaTeX).

Is there an easy way to increase the space here? Ideally I could change a single parameter somewhere, though I think it is unlikely to be this easy. Alternatively, assuming I have to add in space manually each time, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Even with Computer Modern, the transition from a text italic *f* to math can look a bit squeezed.  In that situation, an italic correction `\/` is recommended.  You might try it here,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `mathtools` documentation states quite wisely

> Italic correction is a treacherous area.

As Barbara mentioned in [her comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699314/why-are-these-sentences-in-libertine-so-cramped-and-what-can-i-do-about-it#comment1737756_699314), math is bound to be a bit cramped after an italic *f*. Furthermore, the `libertine` math letters have almost no side bearing, which aggravates the effect:

[image]

(Top: libertine, bottom: CM.)

You've got a couple of workarounds

- As Barbara said, introduce an italic correction `\/` manually.
- Use the option `mathic=true` from the `mathtools` package. For this to work, however, you *must* use the LaTeX inline math syntax `\(...\)`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{mathic=true}

\begin{document}
\itshape
Let $d$ be the dimension of $V$ or of ${}^LG$.

Let $d$ be the dimension of\/ $V$ or of\/ ${}^LG$.

Let $d$ be the dimension of \(V\) or of \({}^LG\).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Take your pick. (Until egreg answers and explains how to do it properly `:-)`.)

Comment: In all three, my eye sees a bit too much space between "V" and "or".

Comment: @murray The italic `o` has a larger side bearing on the left.

Comment: @murray BTW thanks for the edit. While "exaggerate" wasn't what I had in mind, "exasperate" was a false friend.

Comment: The same `o` left-side bearing gives the same, seemingly too-wide gap between "V" and "or" for all the fonts I tried, including CM (and Latin Modern), Tex Gyre Terms, Tex Gyre Schola, and Lucida Bright.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use text mode for this, maybe with a bit of manually added space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\newcommand{\spacesuper}[1]{\,\textsuperscript{#1}}
\begin{document}
\textit{Let $d$ be the dimension of $V$ or of ${}^LG$.}

\textit{Let d be the dimension of V or of \textsuperscript{L}G.}

\textit{Let d be the dimension of V or of \spacesuper{L}G.}
\end{document}
```

[image]